# Use bower.json location as a parameter to bower install

Tags: bower, bower-install

Is it possible to use the bower.json location as a parameter to the bower install command?

Something like:

```
bower install -d /var/www/html/bower.json
```

I would like to run bower install in a single line command and I do not have the option to "cwd" first.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/www/html/your_directory && bower install
```